# Error installing php-devel 5.5 CentOS 6

Tags: centos, php, yum, couchbase

I am trying to run `pecl install couchbase` but am having trouble with php-devel and its dependencies.

When I try to run `yum --enablerepo=remi-php55 install php-devel` I get the following error. My current version of php is 5.5.16. It looks like I need to update the gd lib but when I run `yum check-update` I do not see the gd lib in the list.

Error message:

```
Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
       Requires: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1
       Installed: gd-last-2.1.0-3.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           gd-last(x86-64) = 2.1.0-3.el6.remi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `gd-last` is in the `remi` repository, but you disabled it. You need to enable the repository to install packages from it.

Comment: Is it good practice to disable repo's when not using them?

Comment: Only if you want to be confused whenever you try to install something. :) If you have packages from the repos, you should leave them enabled.